# Draw a TextView inside a custom activity?

Tags: android, view, canvas

I'm implementing a custom `View`, and I need to draw some text in it. The text has to fit in a box (so I have to break it up and make it fit). Because of this, I thought I could use a `TextView` and draw it inside my custom `View`. Here's what I've tried:

```
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, eventRadius, eventRadius, eventBg);

canvas.save();
canvas.clipRect(rect);
TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
tv.setText(e.getSummary());
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
tv.layout(0, 0, (int) (rect.right - rect.left), (int) (rect.bottom - rect.top));
tv.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

However, nothing is showing up. I know `rect` is OK because the first `drawRoundRect` works fine. What am I missing? Is there a better way? Maybe I should extend `ViewGroup` instead? I'm not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it without wrapping:

```
canvas.drawText(yourText, xCoord,YCoord, YourPaint);
```

to do it with wrapping

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        TextPaint tp=new TextPaint();
        tp.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
        tp.setTextSize(12);
        StaticLayout sl=new StaticLayout("THIS IS SOME LONGER TEXT",tp,60,Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,1f,0f,true);
        sl.draw(canvas);
        }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html

Comment: Because it won't wrap the text if it needs to be wrapped.

Comment: you can wrap it yourself by using paint.getTextBounds(char[].int,int,Rect) to determine if it will fit and if not wrap it or change the size.

Comment: edited: look at my second example.  StaticLayout will wrap and you can set the width (in this case I set it to 60)

Comment: I actually went with the manual approach (using `TextPaint.breakText`) in the end, but your solution worked best so I marked it as accepted.

Comment: Thank's for tip on `StaticLayout`! Was searching for exactly that and didn't know it existed

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is this:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
int width = (int) (rect.right - rect.left);
int height = (int) (rect.bottom - rect.top);
textView.layout(0, 0, width, height);
textView.setText(e.getSummary());
Bitmap bitmapText = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvasText = new Canvas(bitmapText);
textView.draw(canvasText);

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapText, rect.left, rect.top, null);
```

It feels dirty (and somewhat un-optimal), but it works. If someone doesn't come up with a better solution I'm going to mark this as accepted in a couple of days.