# How to properly use clipRect?

Tags: android, view, canvas

I'm writing a custom `View`, but I can't really figure out how to use `clipRect` on a `Canvas`. I need this because I'm calling `draw(Canvas)` on another object and I'd like to give it my own (clipped) `Canvas`. My current solution is:

```
StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout(text, tp, (int) (rect.right - rect.left), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1f, 0f, true);

Bitmap layoutBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (rect.right - rect.left), (int) (rect.bottom - rect.top), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas layoutCanvas = new Canvas(layoutBitmap);
sl.draw(layoutCanvas);

canvas.drawBitmap(layoutBitmap, null, rect, null);
```

However, this feels dirty, creating a new bitmap and a new canvas every time (I'm using this method to draw text in a box, see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071188/draw-a-textview-inside-a-custom-activity/)).

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout(text, tp, (int) (rect.right - rect.left), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1f, 0f, true);

canvas.save();
canvas.clipRect(rect, Region.Op.REPLACE);
sl.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

That "feels" much better, except that it doesn't work. Am I using `clipRect` wrong? Do I not understand what it's actually for or how to use it? Please advise.

P.S. My understanding of `clipRect` is that after that `clipRect` call, `0, 0` should actually translate to `rect.left, rect.top`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of experimenting, it seems that `clipRect` only restricts drawing to the given `rect`, so that any draw calls outside that `rect` will be **clipped** to that `rect`. Thus, my understanding of `clipRect` was wrong.

This means that, in order to use `StaticLayout` I'd have to first draw it to a `Bitmap` that is the size of my `rect` and then draw that `Bitmap` to my `Canvas` at the coordinates I need.

However, I have resorted to using `Canvas.drawText` and `TextPaint.breakText` instead (so I don't have to create a `Bitmap` everytime).